# Replacing vertices with piecharts in R

Tags: r, plot, vertices

just a quick question, is it possible to use a piechart plot as the vertex image of another data frame? Or must the entire vertex pie chart be created entirely from the data frame?

On this note, I saw some documentation about possibly using png files using the 'png' package as the vertices, but I saw that it changed all the vertices to the same image. I was hoping to have each vertex to have its own respective piechart.

Just some more info: I used the 'igraph' library to create a plot of the data frame, but I had to create the pie charts from a separate data frame that I processed.

In any case, just a point to the right direction would be of great help to me. Thanks!

Comment: `plotrix::floating.pie` (and Googling "plotrix floating.pie" will help you find other related material)

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, I'd like to use your comment as an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fine with me. I would include a little bit more specific information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers